# JavaScript. Парсинг даты не работает в Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, дата

Столкнулся с проблемой в элементарном, на первый взгляд, скрипте. Дату получаю из JSON, поэтому в примере просто показываю строку, в виде которой мне эта дата приходит. Далее перевожу ее в тип Date, потом объявляю локализацию для месяцев с разделителем в виде запятой. Далее выделяю в отдельные переменные день и месяц. Месяц подставляю локализованный из своей строки с месяцами. Потом вывожу день и месяц. И все работает во всех браузерах, кроме Safari. В сафари день выводится как "NaN", а месяц "undefined".

Пример на jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ArtHodorev/xpvt214o/317995/

HTML:

```
<div id="block">
  <span id="day"></span> <span id="month"></span>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var dateBase = "2018-06-07 11:50:42";
var dateDate = new Date(dateBase);
var monthArr = 'января,февраля,марта,апреля,мая,июня,июля,августа,сентября,октября,ноября,декабря'.split(',');
var dateMonth = monthArr[dateDate.getMonth()];
var dateDay = dateDate.getDay();

var day = $('#day');
var month = $('#month');

day.html(dateDay);
month.html(dateMonth);
```

CSS:

```
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#block {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}
```

Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Шаблон yyyy-MM-dd не является официально валидным для конструктора Date. Некоторые браузеры его поддерживают, но как видно не все.

Пример решения (date.js):

```
var dateBase = "2018-06-07 11:50:42";
var dateDate = Date.parseExact(dateBase, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
```

moment.js:

```
var dateBase = "2018-06-07 11:50:42";
var dateDate= moment(dateBase).format("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
```

Comment: date.js - это отдельная библиотека?

Comment: Да. Еще хорошая библиотека для работы с датами moment.js: moment('2018-06-07 11:50:42').format('yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss')

Comment: C date.js работает! Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Рано я обрадовался) Дата забирается в формате JSON с помощью ajax-запроса. И Date.parseExact на выходе дает null. Т.е. когда dateBase - это статичная строка, то Date.parseExact работает корректно, а когда вместо нее array[i].created (который та же самая строка такого же формата), то выдается null. Есть идеи, почему так? Не успевает подхватить значение чтоли?

Comment: Видать при кастинге строки к дате вы итерируетесь по массиву и сама функция асинхрона. Если да, то используйте замыкание

Answer (score 0):

мне помогло использование, вместо
var dateBase = "2018-06-07 11:50:42";
var dateBase = "2018-06-07T11:50:42.000+03:00";(к примеру для Москвы)